# Mavericks based VOIP solution needed

Tags: macos, skype, voip

I am traveling and as usual, I brought my Vonage box. It blew. So I have a Vonage account and no means to connect to it.

Any ideas? The Vonage App - SoftPhone stopped with 10.4! Vonage Companion doesn't include the global coverage.

Skype only (iirc) handles Skype to Skype calls.

Are there generic apps that can plug into the Vonage ecosystem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a lots of [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) based softphones (Vonage seams to use the SIP protocol) like

- [telephone](http://www.tlphn.com/)
- [iSoftphone](http://www.call4mac.com)

And you have to setup your software to connect to Vonage - maybe the following [link](http://voicent.com/kb/index.php/support/gateway/450/configure-vonage-sip) could help you.

Comment: Thanks very much. That was very helpful. I've installed both Telephone and iSoftPhone, but tackling SIP is more difficult. Telephone comes with a SIP list, but I really hope to get to use the Vonage SIP service. I just don't know how yet. . But since this is a Mac site and you've helped me with that, I'll close out this question in a while. Of course, if you or anyone has Vonage SIP info, that would be most welcome.

Comment: I found little help from Vonage. They do not support soft phone access, and won't release any information on if/how to use it. I may have to switch.

Comment: I´ve found the following [website](http://voicent.com/kb/index.php/support/gateway/450/configure-vonage-sip) with informations how to set up SIP - maybe it works?

Comment: Thanks for that. I've seen the Voicent site. Vonage no longer supports their soft phone service for Mac, and when I read the article, it shows a Windows client. But I appreciate the help (+1). I'm trying a service called VOIPConnect until I can figure this out properly.